# Load View from ajax call without passing values as parameters in the URL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following ajax call on my ASP.NET Application

```
return $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "../ControllerName/MethodName?var1=" + var2 + "&var2=" + var2,
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Error!")
    },
    success: function (result) {
        // Do something with the success.
        // Load a new View and pass the results to it.
    },
    async: true,
    processData: false
});
```

This ajax call goes into the following Controller method.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MethodName(string var1, string var2)
{
    // Do something here
    return Json(new
    {
        isRequestSuccessfull = true,
        userId = userId,
        password = password
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, when I am in the success part of my ajax call, I want to redirect into a new page and pass the username and password information to the new view **without** putting that information in the URL as parameters.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**
I modified the success of the first ajax call with to call this ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../Shared/Success",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { userName: userName, password: password  },
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

And this is the method in the SharedController.

```
public ActionResult Success(string userName, string password)
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = userName;
            ViewBag.Password = password;
            return View("Success");
        }
```

The ajax call goes into the method but when the method returns the View, it doesn't go there but remains in the main view.

Comment: maybe make a post request to the route that will serve the desired view and pass the username and password in to the body?

Comment: You mean like another ajax call?

Comment: precisely. In the success of the first one.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What does it matter if the username and password are GET string parameters, POST parameters (either multipart or url encoded) or sent via some other method. You're still sending them to the server.

Comment: Sounds like no matter what, you've got a serious security lapse if it is indeed username and password in that initial GET...

Comment: How do you suggest to display the data once the controller returns the two values back to the UI from the Controller? (I want do show them as visible data as we are generating bot values for the user). I don't want it to be visible in the URL as they could mark up the page in their favorites and get that info later on...

Comment: Anytime you are sending data to the server. The user can see the data. Just because you're "hiding" it by not putting it in the URL it's still trivial for the user to see it. As @MikeMcCaughan put it, "you've got a serious security lapse" if this is your problem

Comment: Yes, and I am totally fine with it since I will display that information in the UI. What I don't want to do is to put that information in the URL and then let them able to mark down the URL in their favorites.

Comment: You should keep them logged in after the first time they log in, not send the username and password every request. Most of us use things like server sessions for such work. Might I suggest you do some research on how you should write a web application?

Comment: This is not a login question. I am generating a totally different username/password tuple nothing to do with the web app. There is a form that generates that information and then after submitting the form, I want to load a new view with that information. That's it.

Comment: "nothing to do with the web app". You're sending the ajax request from the web app? This is a normal functioning of the app? Then it has everything to do with it. Your question was answered by the first comment. Use a POST request. I'll stand by my comment about doing some research. You can keep arguing and trying to defend your nonsensical position and your arbitrary requirements ( Let me know how that's working for you) but I don't see it doing you much good as I see 0 actual answers (except the comments) to what is a simple to answer question.

Comment: And I am totally fine with the POST request. I will implement a POST Request and re route the call to a new View. This thread got randomized with comments that I wanted to address here and that's what I did.